RLS not working correctly with Google oAuth / supabase
With nextjs I have a google OAuth login with supabase and I want to have specific users to be able to insert, update, delete files. So I've given certain users the role 'service_role' and have added RLS select, update, delete, and insert to the 'images' table with the target role being the 'service_role' from the dropdown on target roles. I continue to get the "new row violates row-level security policy for table 'images'" when trying to insert into the table. Even after the user has their role, there aud and role in the raw_app_meta_data to be 'service_role' and it still fails. I have then tried just 'authenticated' on the target role and tried a brand new user with no changes and it still fails. For now I'll just put images of the RLS policies I've set to see if I'm setting something wrong. And every RLS policy is the same as the delete policy.
RLS policies
RLS delete policy, all others are the same
When the RLS has no target role I'm able to do everything as expected, so my Supabase setup in code can't be wrong.... right?
I've tried changing the roles for the users, changing the RLS policy in countless different ways using the use check with auth.role() = 'service_role'.
If anyone else is having an issue with this, a workaround is to use the service_role secret key in your createClient functions rather than the public anon key. Of course only use the key behind the server and not on the client.
